# Can a Siren's elemental weapons trigger a heal over time effect?

Tags: borderlands-2

I plan on playing a siren at level 50 as a majority healer/support class while my friends are the damage dealers.

The restoration talent in the Harmony tree states "Shooting other players heals them." At 5/5 the skill converts 30% of damage done into healing.

That got me thinking that if my elemental weapons apply damage over time effects to enemies, can it also apply healing over time effects to allies? Or is the heal only from the initial damage and the elemental effect of the bullet has no effect towards the heal?

If it's the latter then keeping high physical damage weapons would be preferable than elemental ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, shooting people with elemental damage won't cause elemental healing; only hits on enemies or reflected bullets that actually hurt players will cause DOT effects.

However apparently elemental multipliers do apply, and other players are considered "flesh" targets regardless of shield; so using Fire weapons should generally be preferable to any other weapon type of similar damage. Generally high ROF guns are best assuming passable damage, since your fellow players are often hard to shoot in motion. I tend to prefer SMGs and shotguns to pistols for healing for example.

Note however that Amp damage seems to apply to healing; The Bee makes for great healing.

Comment: I can test this bit about elemental multipliers, I have a handy siren with me. But later - the siren's already trying to get our baby to bed, and has to get up early, so no coop today :)

Comment: @OrcJMR You don't actually need a siren to test, just an elemental gun. Siren skills don't make a difference in the straight-damage multiplier

Comment: Wait. We know the multipliers of elemental weapons. We are talking about how they multiply Restoration effect, don't we? As in, healing naked friends with fire and shielded ones with shock.

Comment: @OrcJMR oh, right. I suppose you do need the skill to test the skill don't you (you mean there are people who don't play Siren?)

Comment: Yes, there are people who [use a gun. And if that don't work... use more gun.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNgNBsCI4EA)

Comment: Woohoo, I've tested some elements at last. Elemental multipliers do apply, and the character is always considered meat, regardless of shield. Fire did 1.5x, slag and shock 1x weapon damage, including badass bonus. I had no chance to test corrosion and slag, unfortunately. Also, I've noticed the lack of badass bonus for a shotgun - are shotguns broken by Amp nerf on PC as well? :-(

Comment: @OrcJMR damage bonuses on shotties are split over the whole damage not per pellet now I think, that might be why. Try Corrosion if you can, it'd be interesting to see if it's 1x or reduced damage (corrode vs flesh should be lower than 1x)